# Can I center a paragraph having the narrow-width text at the top rather than the bottom?

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment, cs5

Traditional centering looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet
```

I'd like subheadings to be "upside down" or narrow at the top:

```
 Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
```

I'd like to avoid placing a forced line break to make this happen.  Is there a way in InDesign CS5 to put the "remainder" text at the top of the paragraph rather than at the bottom?

***Edit:*** I could have jury-rigged around this problem if CS5 would indent the first line on both the left and the right... but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with the paragraph property Balance Ragged Lines, but the required *value* for this is – strangely – not available in the regular User interface. The interface only allows a yes/no, but the Scripting Interface reveals there are actually more choices available to the formatting engine:

```
BalanceLinesStyle.FULLY_BALANCED    Balances lines equally.
BalanceLinesStyle.NO_BALANCING  Does not balance lines.
BalanceLinesStyle.PYRAMID_SHAPE Prefers longer last lines.
BalanceLinesStyle.VEE_SHAPE Prefers shorter last lines.
```

(http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/pe_BalanceLinesStyle.html)

The UI Off setting corresponds to `BalanceLinesStyle.NO_BALANCING` and the On to `BalanceLinesStyle.VEE_SHAPE`, so the default indeed seems to prefer a longer first line.

If you run this one-line Javascript with the text cursor inside the paragraph to change, you can see it toggles around to prefer *shorter* first lines instead:

```
app.selection[0].balanceRaggedLines = BalanceLinesStyle.PYRAMID_SHAPE;
```

And if you check the paragraph overrides, you can see it is actually recorded as "... + balance: pyramid shape".

Do note that the rule "make the lines as evenly long as possible" still prevails, and so this will still favor

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
```

over

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet
```

It may work for other texts, though.

Comment: I decided to delete my previous comment, which contained considerable gratitude and unfiltered disbelief that the Adobe coders would use a checkbox rather than a dropdown.  THANK YOU!  This works fabulously.

Answer (score 0):

For headlines/subheadlines a vertical triangle with the narrow line at the top:

> A Headline Which Must Be
>   Broken Into Two Lines Due to Length

... or a middle-weighted block

> A Headline Which
>   Must Be Broken Into Three Lines 
>   Due to Its Total Length

.... are actually *best* in my opinion.

Theres no direct way, I'm aware of, to tell InDesign to reverse line length.

You'll have to use a **soft return** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>), which will maintain applied styles to all the lines. Or a hard line feed (<kbd>Return</kbd>), which will break any style into separate applied instances.

In either case, a line feed needs to be manually input.

Comment: I was really hoping this wasn't the case.  There are hundreds of subheadings....

Comment: Well, that's why you earn the big bucks `:)` For some things, there's no alternative but to roll up your sleeves and do it.

Answer (score 0):

From **Paragraph Style Options** check **Balance Ragged Lines**

[image]

Comment: Regrettably, this does not work predictably.  Rather than forcing the remainder text to the top, it's simply auto-margining to better balance the remainder against the body of the text.  Whether or not it flips the remainder text to the top appears to be luck of the word-length draw.